# "There is already an object named 'myTableName' in the database."

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.Net MVC 6 application, I have brought some changes in model
when I run:

```
dnx ef database update
```

I get bellow error:

```
There is already an object named 'myTableName' in the database
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you initializing your context? 
I think the default initializer is "CreateDatabaseIfNotExists". If you changed this somewhow, or have a custom initializer, then you may have the reason for your problem there.

Are you using code migrations in Entity Framework or something else?